# Sumfony - "One of listeners must count and slice given target"

Tags: symfony5

Имею проблему при передачах запроса в метод paginate() пакета "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle"

```
 /**
     * @param integer       $page
     * @param integer       $size
     * @param Option\Locale $locale
     *
     * @return PaginationInterface
     */
    public function all(int $page, int $size, Option\Locale $locale): PaginationInterface
    {
        $qb = $this->connection->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select(
                'so.id',
                'so.option_type_id',
                'so.slug',
                'so.position',
                'so.name as default_name',
                'sot.content as name',
                'sot.locale',
                )
            ->from('shop_options', 'so')
            ->leftJoin(
                'so',
                'shop_option_translations',
                'sot',
                'so.id = sot.object_id and sot.locale = :locale and sot.field = :name_field'
            )
            ->setParameter(':locale', $locale->getName())
            ->setParameter(':name_field', Option\Option::NAME_FIELD)
            ->orderBy('so.position', 'ASC')
            ->execute();

        $pagination = $this->paginator->paginate($qb, $page, $size); // Тут ошибка

        $options = array_map(
            static fn ($option) => $this->denormalizer->denormalize(
                $option,
                TranslatedOption::class,
                'array',
                [AbstractObjectNormalizer::DISABLE_TYPE_ENFORCEMENT => true]
            ),
            (array)$pagination->getItems()
        );

        $pagination->setItems($options);

        return $pagination;
```

Ошибка:

```
{
    "status_code": 500,
    "message": "failure",
    "data": [],
    "meta": [],
    "errors": [
        {
            "error": {
                "message": "0",
                "code": 0
            },
            "details": [],
            "info": "One of listeners must count and slice given target"
        }
    ]
}
```

Без пагинации выборка прекрасно работает, где я ошибся?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все нашол свои косяки:

Во первых:

```
$qb = $this->connection->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select(
                'so.id',
                'so.option_type_id',
                'so.slug',
                'so.position',
                'so.name as default_name',
                'sot.content as name',
                'sot.locale',
                )
            ->from('shop_options', 'so')
            ->leftJoin(
                'so',
                'shop_option_translations',
                'sot',
                'so.id = sot.object_id and sot.locale = :locale and sot.field = :name_field'
            )
            ->setParameter(':locale', $locale->getName())
            ->setParameter(':name_field', Option\Option::NAME_FIELD)
            ->orderBy('so.position', 'ASC')
            //->execute(); // execute() лишний
```

Во вторых использовал $this в контекст статичистого колбека:

```
fn  // Вместо static fn
```